# Dropdown menu not hiding sub categories

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

The sub categories in my menu are always visible, even though their display is set to none. What am I doing wrong?

http://codepen.io/MrAxlee/pen/QwyVMJ

```
<header id="header">
  <!-- Logo -->
    <h1 id="logo">MrAxlee</h1>
  <!-- Nav -->
    <nav id="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Intro</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">What I do</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">My Work</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
          <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

And the CSS

```
#nav ul li ul {
    display:none;
}
    #nav ul li:hover > ul {
        display:block;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"il" is not "li" :-)

this woks great:

```
#nav ul li ul {
    display:none;
}
    #nav ul li:hover > ul {
        display:block;
    }
```

he also had troubles with FTP but now all is OK for him.

Comment: Oops! That was actually a typo from copying it onto here, the typo isn't actually on my site. [link](http://mraxlee.x10.mx) if it helps.

Comment: you have no #nav ul li ul {display:none;} in your css on your site

Comment: [Nav CSS](http://mraxlee.x10.mx/css/nav.css)
[main CSS](http://mraxlee.x10.mx/css/style.css).

Nav CSS takes priority over the main CSS

Comment: put display:none;!important; to be sure that display:none; has priority if this is right, you have to use css precedence : http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/images/specificitywars-05v2.jpg

Comment: I've added the important tag in just incase, but even if I remove all other styles linked to #nav and just leave the #nav ul li ul {display;none;!important;} tag they still don't hide.

Comment: nav.css is inside a noscript

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66481/discussion-between-alex-bunt-and-clement).

Comment: @AlexBunt you can validate a response iy you want

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your css

```
#nav ul il ul {
    display:none;
}
```

It should be #nav ul li ul :)

Comment: Oops! That was actually a typo from copying it onto here, the typo isn't actually on my site. [link](http://mraxlee.x10.mx) if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check out This You misspell **LI** in

```
#nav ul il ul {
    display:none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yufrfueo/

Comment: Oops! That was actually a typo from copying it onto here, the typo isn't actually on my site. [link](http://mraxlee.x10.mx) if it helps.